# What is the best XNA book, which can teach you the 2d & 3d game programming from basic to advance?

Tags: c#, xna

1- What is the best XNA book, which can teach the 2d & 3d game programming from basic to advance? Is it possible after reading that book create professional looking 3d games???

2- Any suggestion how can become professional game developer with XNA, and create cool 3d games?

3- Is it XNA industry standard for creating games?

4- Is there any work place can join as XNA game developer?

Comment: Learn to crawl before you run, starting with XNA is fine, start creating small games (snake, tetris etc..). Don't aim to create professional looking games as a start, as they usually have a development time of several years and have 10+ persons involved in creating the game.

Answer (score 1):

I have this one and I think it's pretty good. It starts out with a simple 2D game that touches on many basic concepts, and then moves on to Audio and Zune before moving on to 3D. Well written and easy to follow.

http://amzn.com/0596521952

Good point in the comments.

Title: Learning XNA 3.0: XNA 3.0 Game Development for the PC, Xbox 360, and Zune

Author: Aaron Reed

ISBN: 0596521952

Comment: It would be helpful to include (select as many as possible from) title, author, publisher, ISBN, so that others can still find the book when the link inevitably stops working.

Comment: I edited and replaced the URL with a permalink, too (it's a little-known official feature of Amazon; click the envelope next to "Share" on the right side of the page and Amazon will show you the amzn.com shortened permalink) - just one more thing to do to try and keep the link unbroken as long as possible! :)

Comment: Learning XNA 4.0 is out now. http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/game-programming/9781449397210

Answer (score 0):

1. Game development is made from many different skills, from which programming is just one of them. Professional 3D game wouldn't just need clever programming, you would need pretty good modeling skills just to begin with. To learn everything from one book - no, so the answer to entire #1 is no.
2. Well, first learn programming. Play with 3D modeling for awhile. Maybe try some scripting engines for creating games, that have a lot of stuff already made, so you wouldn't have to start from scratch. If going for real game development skills, I would recommend extensive C++ learning, and DirectX. XNA could be the part in-between.
3. No. Not by a long shot. Main reasons are performance, and the fact that it came to a market where C++ rules for a long-long time. But, that doesn't mean you can't do some impressive games in it. Computers grow stronger every day, and that means that for a lot of games that are not very high-end on graphics, XNA is a good match.
4. http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=monster+xna+developer&aq=f&aqi=&aql=f&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=76987d56368691f5

Answer (score -1):

I can't answer your other questions, but as for #3, XNA is far from being an industry standard. Most major games (i.e. the ones by large publishing houses that account for the majority of sales) are written in unmanaged DirectX. XNA is mainly for smaller indie developers looking to publish on XBox Live or something.

Comment: or windows. There are a few indie games on steam now-a-days that have been written in XNA :D

But yes, it's mainly used by indies for writting games. Game software houses have started using it to prototype ideas however, but afterwards they will write the full thing in C++.